# Trying to integrate Twig with Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I am trying to integrate Twig in codeigniter HMVC. I am able to do the following things:

1. Custom Twig Extension
2. Extending Parent Template
3. Creating custom Filters
4. Creating custom Function

But i am not able to figure out how i call controller function in my template in codeigniter.

Currently in Codeigniter we do

```
Modules::run('function path',$data]);
```

In symfony we do like

```
{{ render(controller(
        'AppBundle:Default:register'
    )) }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehe, that's something every Symfony2 developer want to implement first :-).

Here is the way I (quickly and dirtily) implemented it:

1) create the following helper:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('twig_render'))
{

    function twig_render()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $route = array_shift($args);

        // @TODO this way do not handle controllers in subfolders
        $controller = APPPATH . 'controllers/' . substr($route, 0, strrpos($route, '/'));

        $explode = explode('/', $route);
        if (count($explode) < 2)
        {
            show_error("twig_render: A twig route is made from format: path/to/controller/action.");
        }

        if (!is_file($controller . '.php'))
        {
            show_error("twig_render: Controller not found: {$controller}");
        }
        if (!is_readable($controller . '.php'))
        {
            show_error("twig_render: Controller not readable: {$controller}");
        }
        require_once($controller . '.php');

        $class = ucfirst(reset(array_slice($explode, count($explode) - 2, 1)));
        if (!class_exists($class))
        {
            show_error("twig_render: Controller file exists, but class not found inside: {$class}");
        }

        $object = new $class();
        if (!($object instanceof CI_Controller))
        {
            show_error("twig_render: Class {$class} is not an instance of CI_Controller");
        }

        $method = $explode[count($explode) - 1];
        if (!method_exists($object, $method))
        {
            show_error("twig_render: Controller method not found: {$method}");
        }

        if (!is_callable(array($object, $method)))
        {
            show_error("twig_render: Controller method not visible: {$method}");
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($object, $method), $args);

        $ci = &get_instance();
        return $ci->output->get_output();
    }

}
```

2) add the following functions to your library (note: site_url already given by Ci):

```
$this->_twig_env->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('site_url', 'site_url')));
$this->_twig_env->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('render', 'twig_render', array('is_safe' => array('html'))));
```

Now you're ready to go, for example, if you have such route:

```
$route['list-partners-on-country-(:num)'] = 'list/partners/$1';
```

To create a link, you can use:

```
<a href="{{ site_url() }}/{{ render('list/partners', country.id) }}" class="btn btn-small">{{ country.name }}</a>
```

Enjoy,

Comment: Dirty.. but I'm sure it works. Is this good MVC structure practice?

Comment: Yes, but such functions should be used when needed only. Imagine the case where you have a table, and just above some filters in a form. When you validate the form, table is refreshed asynchronously. How will you initialize your table at the very first page loading? As your ajax call will call a controller, it sounds like `render()` your controller in your page will be the most appropriate way to go.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter + HMVC + Twig + Doctrine
part of project dynamic cms (blank buildable cms)

you can clone this https://github.com/dandisy/dynamicCMS

### you can create helper content this

```
// for module return string
if(!function_exists('module_run'))
{
    function module_run($module, $param = array())
    {
        echo modules::run($module, $param);
    }
}

// for module return array
if(!function_exists('module_array'))
{
    function module_array($module)
    {
        return modules::run($module);
    }
}
```

then autoload the helper for use in controller and your view